# How to convert string into int?

Tags: asp.net

i have a doubt. May i know how to convert string to int.i know using parse we can do it. instead of parsing is there any thing to convert.

Comment: You could cast the string to an int. Show some code please, for people to understand why `Parse` or `TryParse` wouldn't be of use.

Comment: @silky: You are right. That is really stupid of me to write that.

Comment: shahkalpesh: Hey, we all do stupid things sometimes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no.

You can call

```
int k = Convert.ToInt32("32");
```

But it still parses it.

-- Edit:

For completeness, here is the code to do it without 'framework' functions:

```
    public static int ToInt32 (string s)
    {
        int result = 0;

        foreach(char c in s){
            if( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ){
                result = (result * 10) + (c - '0');
            }
        }

        if( s[0] == '-' ){
            result = -result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Mr. Silky is there any thing i know this. thank you for response

Comment: Thank you for response Mr. silky

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to get the numerical value of the characters in the string?  If so, you could cast individual characters to int to grab the unicode numbers.  Other than that, it doesn't make much sense to not use int.Parse or int.TryParse.

```
public void PrintValues(string aString)
{
    foreach(char c in aString)
    {
        int x = (int)c;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt Mr. Nate. you code is super is it concept of boxing and unboxing

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with boxing/unboxing.

Comment: ok thank you Mr. Jon skeet i understood thank you for response